# Are there Siddurim that have a lot of tefilos that are not used in regular siddurim (lesser-known tefilos)?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book

Tefilos that are in sifrei segulot of diffrent Gedolims seforim

Comment: Avi welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question! It might help to take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) which will help understand how the site works. Maybe you will also be interested by something I wrote to help you understand the site ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites)
 ? I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: BTW if this is you http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/8915/avi-kupchik you should see here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts about merging the accounts